# This do while loop is is going on forever and I can’t get it to stop

Tags: c#

I’m trying to make a game where you have to choose a random number, and the computer will tell you if you’re right or not. But in the code I have, the loop will just keep executing what is in the if command. If I try to break it’ll just do what’s in the while part of it. I want to be able to enter a number, tell you if it’s right or not, and then let you guess  again. Thanks for the help! Also, ignore how part of the code isn’t counting as code. I couldn’t get it to go into the code part, and I didn’t try very hard either. Also sorry about the abnormal variable names.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
namespace newProject
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("useless intro");

            int shortOut;
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int daNumber = rnd.Next(9);
            string userNumber = Console.ReadLine();


            bool isParsable = Int32.TryParse(userNumber, out shortOut);
            if (isParsable)
            {
                do
                {
                    if (shortOut != daNumber)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("no");
                    }
                } while (shortOut != daNumber);
                Console.WriteLine("that's it yeah");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, so you expect the loop to stop when `shortOut == daNumber`, right? In your own words, how is it supposed to happen, in your code, that this becomes satisfied?

Comment: The code is doing exactly what you wrote, an infinite loop if the vars doesn't match, maybe you need to ask again for the number inside the loop if it failed?

Comment: Inside your `do` loop you check the condition `if (shortOut != daNumber)` while `shortOut` never changes and `daNumber` should not change. In order to change the outcome of this  `if (shortOut != daNumber)`  to change you will need to get another value for `shortOut` for the user.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is asking for the user input only once. It then checks if it is an `int` and, if it is, it then starts the loop that never changes the variables. It's going to loop forever.

You need to ask for the user's input repeatedly until they guess correctly. Asking for the input needs to be in the loop. And you should only break out of the loop when they get it right.

Here's how I would do it:

```
Random rnd = new Random();

//choose a number between 0 and 8 inclusive
int daNumber = rnd.Next(9);

// start with a value that the user would never enter
int daGuess = int.MinValue;

//loop if the two numbers are not the same
while (daGuess != daNumber)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter your guess:");
    if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out daGuess))
    {
        if (daGuess != daNumber)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("no");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("that's it yeah");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to check the guess match twice. What you want is an infinite loop that breaks when the condition is true.

```
        int daNumber = new Random().Next(9);

        while(true)
        {
            if (Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int shortOut))
            {                    
                if (shortOut == daNumber)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("that's it yeah");  
                    break;
                }
                Console.WriteLine("no ");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("cannot be parsed as int");
            }
        }
    }
```